# How do I summarize a data frame as a list combined with an ID?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a buyer (`buyerid`) and this buyer can buy several different cars (`carid`).
I would like to list which cars he has bought.
Here I would like to summarize all cars for each buyer and save them as a list.

For example, buyer 1 bought the car with ID 1 and ID 2. This list should now contain `[1,2]`.
How do I make such a list?

If I call method `.values.tolist()` then I get each line as a list, but I want the carid to be summarized by buyers.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Buyerid': [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5],
     'Carid': [1,2,3,4,4,1,2,4,1,3,5],
     'Carid2': [1,2,3,4,4,1,2,4,1,3,5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print(df)

ls = df.values.tolist()
print(ls)

    Buyerid  Carid  Carid2
0         1      1       1
1         1      2       2
2         2      3       3
3         2      4       4
4         3      4       4
5         3      1       1
6         3      2       2
7         4      4       4
8         5      1       1
9         5      3       3
10        5      5       5

[[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 2], [2, 3, 3], [2, 4, 4], [3, 4, 4], [3, 1, 1], [3, 2, 2], [4, 4, 4], [5, 1, 1], [5, 3, 3], [5, 5, 5]]

# What I want as list
[[1,2],[3,4],[4,1,2],[4],[1,3,5]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need select columns for processing use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with `np.unique` if order is not important:

```
L = (df.groupby(['Buyerid'])[['Carid','Carid2']]
       .apply(lambda x: np.unique(x).tolist()).tolist())
```

Or if need processing all columns without `Buyerid` use:

```
L  = (df.set_index('Buyerid')
        .groupby('Buyerid')
        .apply(lambda x: np.unique(x).tolist())
        .tolist())
```

---

```
print (L)
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2, 4], [4], [1, 3, 5]]
```

If ordering is important use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for unpict wit hremove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
L1 = (df.melt('Buyerid')
        .drop_duplicates(['Buyerid','value'])
        .groupby('Buyerid')['value']
        .agg(list)
        .tolist())
print (L1)

[[1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 1, 2], [4], [1, 3, 5]]
```

Comment: ive learned from you, more than any other resource on this internet

Comment: @ombk - Ya, it is super, I learned too 3-4 years ago form another people here ;)

Comment: list(df.groupby("Buyerid").agg(grp_val=("Carid2", lambda x: [i for i in x] )).grp_val)

Comment: @jezrael 
Excuse my question. Is there an option to only use `CarID 1` without `Carid 2`? 
For example, do I receive `CarID 1` and `CarID 2` in a list from `df.melt ('Buyerid')`? Is there where I can only get `CarID 1`?

Comment: @Ella - Sure, then solution is simplier, instead `.apply(lambda x: np.unique(x).tolist()` use `['Carid'].apply(lambda x: np.unique(x).tolist()`